# Django rest_social_auth log in. What to do with facebook token?

Tags: django, facebook, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I am using [django-rest-social-auth](https://github.com/st4lk/django-rest-social-auth) package to allow users authenticate in my Django rest app. I was able to retrieve a token from facebook for an user. Now, I don't know how to use that token. I am trying to access an endpoint that requires logged in users, but I see accesses only as anonymous user when I debug. I've been googleing this issue and tried a lot of different methods (different cookies, url params, etc.).

This is my particular case:

views.py

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

I obtained my token calling http://localhost:8000/api/login/social/token/ (I was following the [django-rest-social-auth](https://github.com/st4lk/django-rest-social-auth) readme) and it looks like:

```
{"token": "4571b2dce1f3abec34b28a4c7bd981c248a30698"}
```

I have that token linked with my user and I can see it in my admin (Home › Auth Token › Tokens)

If I delete the `@login_required` I can access home without any issue. How can I send a request via postman to access that resource using my token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some study I found a solution. There are 2 considerations here:

- **Django needs permission and authentication classes**

My views.py now looks like this:

```
class AuthDetailView(BaseDetailView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, )
    permission_classes = IsAuthenticated,
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'home.html')
```

Notice that I don't have the `@login_required` anymore.

- **Django likes the authorization header with a 'Token' instead a 'Bearer' in front of it**

When I make a call to my api, auth header should be like `Authorization: Token 4571b2dce1f3abec34b28a4c7bd981c248a30698` instead `Authorization: Bearer 4571b2d...`

After this changes, `request.user` is automatically bound to the user previously linked to the token above.

Answer (score 1):

Add `Authorization: Bearer 4571b2dce1f3abec34b28a4c7bd981c248a30698` to the headers as shown below:

[image]

Comment: I tried this way and didn't work. I tried with header `Application-Authorization:4571b2dce1f3abec34b28a4c7bd981c248a30698` too and nothing. Honestly, I don't know what I am doing wrong...